# How to embed jEdit in a JTabbedPane (or JInternalFrame)

Tags: jedit

jEdit is great, and I would like to include it in JTabbedPane.
From the API it seems to be possible but I have been unable to achieve this.

By any chance do you have a simple example that works ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean just the text area?
Well, you can build the text area as library JAR for you to use with the ant target `build-textArea`.
But be aware that the standalone textarea is also under GPL like whole rest of jEdit, so if you plan to release your work, you have to release it under GPL too. If it is just for your private use, you can use it like you want of course.
The package also has `StandaloneTextArea` which demonstrate how to use the text area outside jEdit. You can just run the built JAR, it is an executable JAR that runs this example `StandaloneTextArea`.